# Framer Motion changes y-axis value because of flexbox

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-animations, hamburger-menu, framer-motion

I am using Framer Motion to animate my hambuger menu. I want to make my nav items and icons slide from left to right or from right to left. However the animation on the items changes their y-axis value during the animation **on mobile**. I figured out that this happens because of setting

```
justify-content: space-between
```

on the navbar. I only want the items to slide in a horizontal line.

Here is a url to my problem in codesandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/great-pasteur-nvbvfn?file=%2Fcomponents%2FNavbar.tsx)